# How to translate the default value in p-multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng, angular4-forms, primeng-dropdowns

I am using angular 4 for my web application.Here i want to translate the defaultlabel value of multiselect dropdown.Below format is not working properly. Can anyone help me to sort out this?

.ts

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

.html

```
<div>
   <p-multiSelect [options]="person" formControlName="ExeUser" 
    defaultLabel="{{'CHOOSE' | translate}}"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: No.I didnt get any error

Comment: put `{{'CHOOSE' | translate}}` outside of p-multiselect, is it working ?

Comment: Yes its working other than p-multiselect

Comment: Try to pass defaultLabel as an input. [defaultLabel]="'choose' | translate"

Comment: Its working perfectly whenever i make changes in the dropdown.But it should have worked when i changed the language

Comment: @ancy Did you solve this? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set **defaultLabel** as an input for the multi-select component.
Example:

```html
<div>
   <p-multiSelect [options]="person" formControlName="ExeUser" 
    [defaultLabel]="'CHOOSE' | translate"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work whenever i change the language.But here,the value is translated after i selected or unselected the value in the dropdown(i.e events)